# Nginx how to redirect request for only a certain directory path to index.php in that directory?

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, config

I have some websites like

http://localhost/myweb1

http://localhost/myweb2
and so on.

I need to redirect below example request for myweb1 to index.php in http://localhost/myweb1/index.php
while myweb2 should not be affected.

http://localhost/myweb1/user

http://localhost/myweb1/user/account

http://localhost/myweb1/product
and so on should be redirected to myweb1/index.php

Below is my config at /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add `location /myweb1 { try_files $uri $uri/ /myweb1/index.php; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks, I added that and it's almost working except request with direct file name like myweb1.css or myweb1.js also gets redirected to index.php which caused the webpage unable to load those resources. How do I make it only request without file extension gets redirected?

Comment: Are you saying these files to not exist, so you want Nginx to respond with 404 instead? Use: `location ~ \.(css|js)$ {}` (the empty braces is all you need)

Comment: @RichardSmith These files exists and should be able to access but it's been redirected to index.php now. For example, localhost/myweb1/user will load a webpage which needs to load a css file at localhost/myweb1/myweb1.css but now access to myweb1.css has been redirected to index.php which is not correct. So what I need is request like myweb1/user should be redirect to index.php but request like myweb1/myweb1.css or myweb1/myweb1.js and etc should not be redirect to index.php. In short, only request without any file extension should be redirect to index.php.

Comment: I see the problem. Your `root` statements are in the wrong place. Instead of having an identical `root` statement in each `location` block, you should use one `root` statement in the `server` block which allows it to be inherited by each `location` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith Those statements was added according to a Nginx PHP setup guide. I thought those are standard statements to enable php-fpm? Is there a way to add a condition check in `location /myweb1 { try_files $uri $uri/ /myweb1/index.php; }` to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know where you get your guides from, but check [this Pitfalls and Common Mistakes article](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block).

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for the info. Added a root on top and removed the other root in location blocks and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by
[@RichardSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
location /myweb1 { try_files $uri $uri/ /myweb1/index.php; }
```